# How to efficiently maximize $\log \det$?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{{\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{n \times h}}{\text{maximize}} & \log \det \left({\bf I} + {\bf Z} {\bf Z}^{T}\right)\\ \text{subject to} & {\bf Z} = {\bf A} {\bf X} \\ & \| {\bf Z} \|_{\text{F}} = 1 \end{array}$$

where ${\bf X} \in \Bbb R^{h \times m}$ and ${\bf Z} \in \Bbb R^{n\times m}$. There is no restriction on whether $n$ or $m$ is larger. Also, $h>n$.

How can I efficiently analyze and solve this optimization problem? Are there good reformulations or relaxations to it, or any efficient/special algorithms I shall investigate?

Comment: This appears to me to be a not so easy to solve non-convex optimization problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mark! I am still investigating...but do you have any good ideas?

Comment: How is $X$ full rank when it is not square?

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  First letters of the alphabet for knowns, last letters for unknowns. $A$ is a bad name for an optimization variable.

Comment: Did you apply  log det = tr log  ?